# Transactions With MetaMask Returns An Internal JSON RPC Error

Tags: polygon, payment, web3js, metamask

This is the error MetaMask gives when my app prompts to open it:

```
{"message": "Error Domain=org.walletconnect Code=-32000 \"Internal JSON-RPC error.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Internal JSON-RPC error.}"}
```

I tried changing my MetaMask Mumbai Polygon TestNet RPC to the same as the one in my app
(I am using a third party provider called **particle.network**).

I was looking to get guidance on what might be returning this error message?

Comment: Are you looking for a collection of errors?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, you may need these:

**Parse Ethers.js errors with ease**

- https://github.com/enzoferey/ethers-error-parser

**MetaMask official**

- https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-rpc-errors
- https://github.com/MetaMask/eth-rpc-errors/blob/main/src/error-constants.ts